# Possible to execute javascript on PHP image rendering script?

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic-image-generation

I need to create a php script that renders an image... no problem.

However, what i'd like to do is have the image rendering script trigger some javascript code whenever the script is started up.

Is it possible to include javascript code within the image generating php script without it screwing up the image?

Comment: No.  Javascript runs on the client, and images cannot contain Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you add some javascript code into the image the browser will not run it.

Comment: Is there a way to send a request to a second page when the image is called?

Comment: You can attach *onload* handler to the image tag to see when the image is loaded.

Comment: The image being generated will be going into an email... So i can't put an onload to the img tag :(

Comment: @Brds: You can't run JS in emails, _period_.

Comment: Right, I was trying to run JS in the script that generates the image used in the email, not in the email itself.  I'm wondering if maybe a header() call in the script might do the job.

Comment: @Brds: That doesn't make any sense.  JS only runs on the client, and email clients will never run any JS.

Comment: I wasn't trying to run the javascript FROM the email.  I was planning on putting a dynamic image src in the email (i.e. <img src='www.mysite.com/createImage.php' />) and then have that php script run some javascript... but it seems like it's a no go.